# Entity Framework on .Net Core Server with multiple databases

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a hoster that only offers databases with 2 GB. However, my application will soon need significantly more. The provider wants to provide me with several databases.

Do I have to write a separate DBContext for each database or can I somehow configure Entity Framework to manage it? Is it better later handling, to subscibe otherwhere a bigger database?

Comment: If they choose to host toy databases only I guess it's time to find another hosting service. This would be a very bad reason for splitting up a database. What about referential integrity? What if one of the parts outgrows 2GB?

Comment: You need a separate DbContext for each database. But as Gert said, this is asking for trouble.